# Tree related task from spoj. Gao on a tree ( GOT )

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

There's a tree, with each vertex assigned a number. For each query (a, b, c), you are asked whether there is a vertex on the path from `a` to `b`, which is assigned number `c`.

There can be duplicate assignments of numbers, which means more than one node can be assigned the same number.

I've thought of some solution involving LCA, converting the tree nodes into intervals, but was not quite able to optimize it so the solution will timeout.

Can anyone help with the idea? This is the link to the problem:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/GOT/

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")
#pragma GCC target ("sse4")
#pragma comment(linker, "/stack:200000000")
#pragma GCC optimize ("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target ("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4,popcnt,abm,mmx,avx,tune=native")
#include<bits/stdc++.h>  
using namespace std;

#define ff          first   
#define ss          second
#define pb          push_back
#define pf          push_front
#define pob         pop_back
#define pof         pop_front
#define mp          make_pair
#define ins         insert
#define ll          long long int
#define ld          long double
#define ull         unsigned long long
#define loop(i,n)   for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
#define loop1(i,n)  for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)
#define rev(i,n)    for(ll i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
#define rev1(i,n)   for(ll i=n;i>=1;i--)
#define test(t)     int t;cin>>t;while(t--)
#define endl        '\n'
#define all(c)      (c).begin(), (c).end()
#define tr(c,it)    for(auto it=(c).begin(); it!=(c).end(); it++)
#define rtr(c,it)   for(auto it=(c).rbegin(); it!=(c).rend(); it++)
#define sz(c)       (c).size()
// Define mod as per requirement
const ll MOD =1000000007;
//const ll MOD= 998244353; 
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<ll> vll;
typedef vector<bool> vb;
typedef vector<vector<int> > vvi;
typedef vector<vector<ll> > vvll;
typedef pair<ll,ll> pll;
typedef pair<int,int> pi;
typedef vector<pair<ll,ll> > vpll;
typedef vector<vector<pair<ll,ll> > > vvpll; 
struct Order1{bool operator()(pll const& a,pll const& b)const{return (a.ss < b.ss || (a.ss == b.ss && a.ff < b.ff));}};
struct Order2{bool operator()(pll const& a,pll const& b)const{return (a.ff < b.ff || (a.ff == b.ff && a.ss < b.ss));}};
typedef priority_queue <ll> maxpq;// maximum priority_queue
typedef priority_queue <ll, vector<ll>, greater<ll> > minpq; //minimum priority_queue
typedef priority_queue <pll> maxpq_pair_f;// maximum priority_queue for pairs with maximum ff
typedef priority_queue <pll,vector<pll>, Order2 > max_pq_s; // maximum priority_queue for pairs with maximum ss
typedef priority_queue< pll, vector<pll>, greater<pll> > minpq_pair_f; //minimum priority_queue for pairs with the smallest ff
typedef priority_queue< pll, vector<pll>, Order1 > minpq_pair_s; //minimum priority_queue for pairs with the smallest ss

long long min(long long a,long long b){if(b<=a)return b;return a;}
long long max(long long a,long long b){if(a>=b)return a;return b;}
long long add(long long x, long long y){x += y;while(x >= MOD) x -= MOD;while(x < 0) x += MOD;return x;}
long long multiply(long long x, long long y){return (x * 1ll * y) % MOD;}
long long power(long long x, long long y){long long z = 1;while(y){if(y & 1) z = multiply(z, x);x = multiply(x, x);y >>= 1;}return z;}
long long modInverse(long long x){return power(x, MOD - 2);}
long long divide(long long x, long long y){return multiply(x, modInverse(y));}
long long gcd(long long a,long long b) { if(a == 0)return b;return gcd(b % a, a);}
long long lcm(long long a,long long b){long long val=max(a,b)/gcd(a,b);val*=min(a,b);return val;} 
const long long N=200050; // can be changed as per constraints
long long fact[N]; // array to store values of factorial
void cal_factorial(){fact[0] = 1;for(long long i = 1; i < N; i++)fact[i] = multiply(fact[i - 1], i);}// function to calculate factorial upto N
long long nCr(long long n, long long k){return divide(fact[n], multiply(fact[k], fact[n - k]));}
void BOOST(){ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);}
bool inc(long long x,long long y){return x<=y;}// for increasing order
bool dec(long long x,long long y){return x>=y;}// for decreasing order
// For union and intersection of vectors
vector<int>Intersection(vi &v1,vi&v2){vi v3;sort(all(v1));sort(all(v2));set_intersection(all(v1),all(v2),back_inserter(v3));return v3;}
vector<int>Union(vi &v1,vi&v2){vi v3;sort(all(v1));sort(all(v2));set_union(all(v1),all(v2),back_inserter(v3));return v3;}


vector<int>graph[100010];
int level[100010];
int LCA[100010][21];
int start[100010];
int finish[100010];
int euler_tour[2*100010];
int name[100010];// the number assigned to each vertex
int ans[200050];
int freq[100010];
int assigned[100010];
int timer=1;
int n,q;
const int block=450;
struct query{
    int l;
    int r;
    int index;
    int c;
    bool is_LCA;
    int lca;
};
query Q[200050];
bool comp(query q1,query q2){
    int val1=q1.l/block;
    int val2=q2.l/block;
    if(val1!=val2)
        return val1<val2;
    return q1.r<q2.r;
}

void dfs(int node,int par,int lvl){
    start[node]=timer;
    euler_tour[timer]=node;
    level[node]=lvl;
    LCA[node][0]=par;
    timer++;
    for(auto child:graph[node]){
        if(child!=par)
            dfs(child,node,lvl+1);
    }

    finish[node]=timer;
    euler_tour[timer]=node;
    timer++;
}

void sparse_table(){
    memset(LCA,-1,sizeof(LCA));
    dfs(1,-1,0);
    for(int j=1;j<=20;j++){
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            if(LCA[i][j-1]!=-1)
                LCA[i][j]=LCA[LCA[i][j-1]][j-1];
    }
}
int find_LCA(int a,int b){
    if(level[a]>level[b])
        swap(a,b);
    int d=level[b]-level[a];
    while(d>0){
        int jump=log2(d);
        b=LCA[b][jump];
        d=d-(1<<jump);
    }
    if(a==b)
        return a;
    for(int i=20;i>=0;i--){
        if(LCA[a][i]!=-1 && LCA[a][i]!=LCA[b][i]){
            a=LCA[a][i];
            b=LCA[b][i];
        }
    }
    return LCA[a][0];
}

void add(int i){
    int node=euler_tour[i];
    freq[node]++;
    if(freq[node]==2){
        assigned[name[node]]--;
        return;
    }
    assigned[name[node]]++;

}
void remove(int i){
    int node=euler_tour[i];
    freq[node]--;
    if(freq[node]==1){
        assigned[name[node]]++;
        return;
    }
    assigned[name[node]]--;
}

void clear_everything(){
    for(int i=0;i<100010;i++)
        graph[i].clear();
    memset(freq,0,sizeof(freq));
}

static int uget(){
    int c;
    while(c = getchar(), isspace(c)) {}
    int n = c - '0';
    while(c = getchar(), isdigit(c)) { n = n * 10 + (c - '0'); }
    return n;
}

int main(){
    BOOST();
    int t=0;
    while(scanf("%d%d", &n,&q) != EOF){
        if(t>0)putchar('\n');
        t++;
        clear_everything();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            name[i]=uget();
        for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
            int u,v;
            u=uget();
            v=uget();
            graph[u].pb(v);
            graph[v].pb(u);
        }
        sparse_table();
        for(int i=1;i<=q;i++){
            int a,b,c;
            a=uget();
            b=uget();
            c=uget();
            int lca=find_LCA(a,b);
            if(start[a]>start[b])
                swap(a,b);
            if(lca==a || lca==b){
                Q[i].l=start[a];
                Q[i].r=start[b];
                Q[i].index=i;
                Q[i].c=c;
                Q[i].is_LCA=true;
                Q[i].lca=-1;
                continue;
            }
            Q[i].l=finish[a];
            Q[i].r=start[b];
            Q[i].index=i;
            Q[i].c=c;
            Q[i].is_LCA=false;
            Q[i].lca=lca;
        }

        sort(Q+1,Q+1+q,comp);
        int MoLeft=1,MoRight=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=q;i++){
            int L=Q[i].l;
            int R=Q[i].r;
            int to_find=Q[i].c;
            int id=Q[i].index;

            while(L>MoLeft){remove(MoLeft);MoLeft++;}
            while(L<MoLeft){MoLeft--;add(MoLeft);}
            while(R>MoRight){MoRight++;add(MoRight);}
            while(R<MoRight){remove(MoRight);MoRight--;}

            if(Q[i].is_LCA){
                if(assigned[to_find]>0)
                    ans[id]=1;
                else
                    ans[id]=0;
            }
            else{
                if(assigned[to_find])
                    ans[id]=1;
                else if(name[Q[i].lca]==to_find)
                    ans[id]=1;
                else
                    ans[id]=0;
            }
        }

        for(int i=1;i<=q;i++){
            if(ans[i])puts("Find");
            else
                puts("NotFind");
        }
    }

}
```